# Zkoss listbox+frozen+hide_column

Tags: listbox, visibility, zk

I use listbox with one frozen column. it's working fine but if i hide last (only last) column , i'll get problem with listbox's content. Header scrolls normaly but all rows of listbox appear.

ZK-8.5.2.1-Eval

I use olde frozen - listbox.setAttribute("org.zkoss.zul.frozen.smooth", false);

[image]

Comment: Hello Станислав. Welcome to SO. Please, it's very important that you take the time to read the following guides, then repost your question.

1. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
2. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Once you've read you'll find it easy to prepare a question to get good answers and real help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to try the latest version ZK 8.6.0.1 first? The release notes ([8.6.0](https://www.zkoss.org/product/zk/releasenote/8.6.0) / [8.6.0.1](https://www.zkoss.org/product/zk/releasenote/8.6.0.1)) indicate errors being fixed regarding [frozen and listheaders](https://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-3588) maybe the problem doesn't happen anymore with the latest version.
It the problem still exists it would help if you can provide a reproducing/runnable example e.g. on [zkfiddle.org](http://zkfiddle.org/) Please, save and post the link or url-path here.